# How to add ScrollView for this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic-data

I want to add the scrollview in my application. The application contains two linear layouts in which I add data dynamically. I want to scroll all the screen, so it shows all the data. When I try to add  it shows error,"Scroll view can have only one child". How to add Scrollview in the layout.xml?

Here is my Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/myapp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_logo" 
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label1"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_logo" />

   <Spinner 
       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/label1"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
        android:text="@string/label2" />

   <Spinner 
       android:id="@+id/spinner2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/label2"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:text="@string/label3" />


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/label3"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/submit_button"
       android:layout_below="@id/list2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/submit_button"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/submit_button"
        android:text="@string/label4" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_below="@id/label4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just put Relative layout inside scrollview it will do the trick

Comment: How to add Footer image in the same layout? When I added footer image, It get overlapped with dynamic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScrollView is very similar to FrameLayout. They both tend to work better when there is only one view in there. Make the ScrollView the parent View and place everything inside of there.

Comment: Scroll View doesn't work better it works only when there is only "ONE" direct child.

Answer (score 0):

Like it says, a scrollview can have only one child, just put a layout as a child and all your content in this layout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myapp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_logo" 
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label1"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_logo" />

   <Spinner 
       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/label1"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
        android:text="@string/label2" />

   <Spinner 
       android:id="@+id/spinner2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/label2"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:text="@string/label3" />


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/label3"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/submit_button"
       android:layout_below="@id/list2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/submit_button"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/submit_button"
        android:text="@string/label4" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_below="@id/label4" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put Relative layout inside scrollview it will do the trick

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/myapp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ss"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_logo" />

   <Spinner 
       android:id="@+id/spinner1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/label1"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
        android:text="ss" />

   <Spinner 
       android:id="@+id/spinner2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/label2"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:text="ss" />


   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/label3"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/submit_button"
       android:layout_below="@id/list"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="sss"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/submit_button"
        android:text="ssss" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_below="@id/label4" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap whole Layout inside Relative Layout or FrameLayout
And then add ScrollView
ScrollView can have only one direct element as child

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--         yourLayout here -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView
```